# Dynamic table size html

Tags: html, css, dynamic, background, html-table

I'm making a website that has to fit in the entire screen regardless of screen-size. I'm using a table to use this at the moment but I ran into a problem.

The web page is divided into 3 columns: 
the left column stays at the left of the screen and has a fixed size with a background.
the right column stays at the right of the screen and has a fixed size with a background.
the middle column should be stretched between his neighbouring cells and should have a background that stretches with it (only horizontally)

This way the web page should always look as it was made for the screen you're using to view the site.

However my problem is the middle cell, the image doesn't repeat, somehow the css code: `background-repeat:x-repeat;` doesn't make the image stretch, also when I put the cell width on 100% it interferes with his neighbouring cells making it look like a mess.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT

Here is the markup I'm using:

CSS:

```
#topleftcell
{
    background-image:url(../images/Logo.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:300px;
}
#topmiddlecell
{
    background-image:url(../images/header_fill.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    width:auto;
}
#toprightcell
{
    background-image:url(../images/header_right.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:16px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr style=" width:100%;">
     <td id="topleftcell"></td>
     <td id="topmiddlecell"></td>
     <td id="toprightcell"></td>
 </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: You should be using CSS, not a table to do that.

Comment: There is a big difference between CSS and a table.
I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: You should be using markup that describes your content (which a table doesn't) and styling it to look the way you want. http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/

Comment: I AM using CSS to style the table. If that is what you advise me to do

Comment: It's `repeat-x` not `x-repeat`. However if you don't specify a `background-repeat` it should by default repeat in both directions. Let's see some markup. (And yes, it should be trivially easy to do a layout as simple as three-columns-center-liquid with just CSS positioning and no tables.)

Comment: Added my code to the question

Comment: No, the advise is to not use a table at all when you just want to divide a page into columns. Use a table to describe relationships between bits of data where everything in each row has something in common with each other and everything in each column has something in common with each other. For example, a monthly calendar - every cell in a column represents the same day of the week, and every row is the same week of the year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed width on left and right cell.
auto width in center cell. you probably need a filler image in the center cell.

Comment: I have a filler image, but how do I get it to fill? It doesn't stretch (or repeat) to fill the entire cell. 
I have all the cells where I want them to be but I need the image to fill up now.

Comment: put <img src='filler.jpg'> inside ur center cell. also set the background to fill.jpg repeat-x

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks. though I'm going to use div elements to make the site-layout, I found that the table had to many restriction for my design to work.