# Expanding dynamic background

Tags: html, css, dynamic

I have a centered wrapper div that includes a header, three content columns with (css-based) dynamic height based on content length, and a footer.

Now I want a backround, that expands the colors of those elements in width to the left and right.

Here is a js-fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SLvYx/

So I want the top-left corner to be red, the middle-left to be yellow, the bottom-left to be green, and so on.
My first solution was to use a background .png with a width of 2500px for the body, but that was before the content-based dynamic height of the columns was implemented after recognized to be essential.

I am afraid there might be no pure html/css based solution, but JQuery or javascript is also an option, although I'm just a beginner concerning scripting.
Maybe I'm thinkin to little out of the box, maybe I have to redo the whole html structure to accomplish this, but I wouldn't mind. :-)

I searched almost everywhere, but couldn't find that specific case anywhere around.

Help would be very much appreciated, so thanks in advancce to all who look into this.

EDIT: I found this post: [Dynamic table size html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775715/dynamic-table-size-html?rq=1) that could help, maybe this is a solution, to be using a table with 5 columns, 1st for the left background, 2nd-4th for the content, and the 5th for the right background... is this warmly recommended, or should I keep tables out of this?

Here is the full code of my demo again:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />  <title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {margin:0;}
#wrapper {margin: 0px auto; width: 940px;}
#header {background:red; height:100px;}
#content_wrapper {width: 940px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background: #CCC; overflow: hidden;}
#leftcolumn {background:yellow; width: 470px; float:left; height:auto; min-height: 680px;}
#middlecolumn {background:goldenrod; width: 235px; float:left; height:100%; margin-bottom: -1000px; padding-bottom: 1000px;}
#rightcolumn {background:darkgoldenrod ; width: 235px; float:left; height:100%;margin-bottom: -1000px; padding-bottom: 1000px;}
#footer {background:lightgreen; height:100px;}
</style>
</head> 
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
        Header
    </div>

        <div id="content_wrapper">        

            <div id="leftcolumn">
                Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />Left Column<br />
            </div>

            <div id="middlecolumn">
                Middle Column
            </div>

            <div id="rightcolumn">
                Right Column
            </div>

        </div>    

    <div id="footer">
        Footer
    </div>

</div>    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need javascript or tables. Regular ol' (div-based) HTML and CSS will do the trick.

What you need to do is to restructure your page slightly. Instead of relying on the wrapper div, stack your three main sections, and then have an inner div within each that is your desired width. See the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLvYx/1/).

I've added a (admittedly non-semantic) div in each section with the class "inner", which gets the 940 width you're after.

The only trick now is the middle section. What you want to do is to create a really wide, short image. Say, 3000px wide by 1px tall. Split it 50/50 so that the left side is yellow, and the right side is darkgoldenrod. If you use that image as the background of content_wrapper, and have it tile vertically, it will give the illusion of the color extending off the sides. This will work in most browsers.

If you don't care about older browsers, you could even go a step further and use CSS Gradients on the background of content_wrapper. [See this even further updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLvYx/2/).

The gradients won't work in IE9 or below - but that's okay, because the image is in the style sheet as a fall back.

Comment: Yes, the "inner" div does it, great, thanks alot! So, I was actually thinking too little INSIDE the box, hehe. Today I already testet around with a table, wich also works, but this solution keeps the html much clearer, even with the non-semantic inner div. But who cares about semantics, if it works perfectly after all :-) Big thanks again!!!